# awakeFromNib is not called in my ViewController

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller that is created via initWithNibName, and I just found out awakeFromNib is not called.  Is awakeFromNib only called when the view controller is unarchived from the Nib? (that is, initWithCoder is called)

Answer (score 18):

I think what you're looking for is `viewDidLoad`. `awakeFromNib` is only called on objects that are loaded from the nib. The controller itself receives `viewDidLoad:`. Since you're calling `initWithNibName:bundle:`, it's not actually unarchived from the nib!

Comment: I am aware of the fact that viewDidLoad will be called, but wasn't sure why awakeFromNib wasn't, because the view controller is a file owner of the NIB, so it will be unarchived and its IBOutlet and IBAction hooked up, or so I thought.

Comment: The file owner is a proxy for the UIViewController - not an actual instance. Presumably the view controller is instantiated outside of the scope of the NIB and then 'wired up' according to the relationships specified on the proxy object - the file owner.

Answer (score 4):

UIViewController loads its view lazily, only when it is needed for display.  This goes for both programmatically creating the view using -loadView or unarchiving from a nib.

You can cause the view to load by referencing the UIViewController's view property.

Comment: Thanks for the "reference the view property" tip, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

awakeFromNib is not called for placeholder objects such as File's Owner and First Responder in iOS.  See #4 in the [Object Loading Process Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19)